# Can I distinguish specific instances of Gnome Terminal in the switcher?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, application-switcher

I frequently use [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) for IRC, which is typically run from within a terminal. I have a launcher (`.desktop` file) set up to launch it with the appropriate Gnome Terminal profile, and that works fine.

But when I want to switch back to it via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, I have to then cycle through terminal instances (using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>) to find Irssi.

Is there a way to trick the Gnome 3 switcher into thinking it's a distinct application from other terminal instances; perhaps even giving it it's own icon so I can visually distinguish it while switching?

I am aware of the AlternateTab extension, but I'd rather preserve the normal behaviour for all other apps if possible.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm also using the Gnome 3 Team PPA, so Gnome Terminal is at 3.10.

Comment: Does the window name differ from other terminal windows?

Comment: Yes, irssi has an add-on script that does that.

Comment: (And it's also possible to set via the `.desktop` file using one of `gnome-terminal`'s options.)

Comment: Not literally what you asked for, but would it be a solution then to create a keyboard shortcut, calling a tiny script that checks if the window: <windowname> exists, if not, runs Irssi, else raises its window?

Comment: I don't think that would help my workflow much over what it is currently (`alt`+`tab` and `alt`+``` vs a third arbitrary shortcut) :/

Comment: (I should mention that my current leading idea is to write a separate C program that uses `exec` or `system` to do this, which hopefully the Gnome switcher will think is a different program.)

Comment: It would be a *single* action instead of browsing through the windows. All windows owned by the same application will always appear under the same icon / will be seen as originated by one application by Unity.

Comment: I see your point, but it's still a break from the usual habit. It's not Unity BTW, I'm using Gnome 3.

Comment: Ah sorry, but it is the same, the switcher listens to the same "source".

Answer (score 0):

### This is a hack!

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/gnome-terminal ~/bin/detly-terminal
```

Now change your `Irssi.desktop` file to use `detly-terminal`

*Tested and works on Unity*

If that would fail and you're ready to program something anyway, I would: download the [source code](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gnome-terminal/3.14/), do a `sed` and replace `gnome-terminal` with `detley-terminal`, and recompile...

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You mean for the launcher? Yep :/

Comment: Chat???  Ubuntu  general room???

Comment: OK, let me go over my settings: `gnome-terminal` has a `.desktop` file with a customized steampunk icon. `detley-terminal` is in `~/bin` and has no `.desktop` file.  If I launch `detley-terminal` in the same session as the gnome one, I get a steampunk icon and an ugly gnome terminal icon that I can [Alt][Tab] between...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying a similar thing. I have an `extra-gnome-terminal` in `~/Code/bin` (which is on my `$PATH`). If I just launch `extra-gnome-terminal` from a console, the switcher groups it with `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Oh, I missed "Gnome 3" I'm using Unity...  I'm going to have a look at the source code.

Comment: If my hack doesn't work, (It works just fine on my system in unity) I would download the source code, do a `sed` and replace  "gnome-terminal" with "detley-terminal", and recompile...